# Protoype with instances of a component in Figma

Tags: prototype, figma

Is there a way to achieve the following in the Figma Prototype?

I have a component, that has three variants, Default, Hover, and Selected. What I want to do is to use two instances of this component and both of them have the hover state, but clicking an instance changes it to the selected state but deselects the other instance.
I know how to do interaction prototypes, but don’t know how to have different states for the instances of the same component in a single design.

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about programming. This is off topic for this forum.